# Spring custom @Query with incrementable variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a query that map to a Custom Object :

```
@Query("SELECT new com.mypackage.CmcXml(c.nom, c.prenom, c.genre "+
                "FROM Cmc c")
List<CmcXml> getExportCmc();
```

So I get this kind of result :

```
{"NOM1", "PRENOM1", "GENRE1"},
{"NOM2", "PRENOM2", "GENRE2"},
{"NOM3", "PRENOM3", "GENRE3"}
```

I would like to have an counter that increment while retrieving the data :

```
@Query("SELECT new com.mypackage.CmcXml(myCounter, c.nom, c.prenom, c.genre "+
                "FROM Cmc c")
List<CmcXml> getExportCmc();
```

The result I want :

```
{1, "NOM1", "PRENOM1", "GENRE1"},
{2, "NOM2", "PRENOM2", "GENRE2"},
{3, "NOM3", "PRENOM3", "GENRE3"}
```

Is it possible to do it in the @Query or do I have to go through all the list after the request ?

Comment: You already have a counter, the index of the item in the `List`

Comment: Yes but I would like to be able to create my Object with the counter in the @Query (see my edited question)

Comment: Get your objects without any counter with your query, and then use your business logic to map thos objects to objects with a counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , row number is not supported in jpa/hibernate. you have to use native query.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in JPA as JPA operates to entities and entities are in turn mapped to tables in database. Row number corresponds to a result set and not actually exists in database table.

You can try something as below using native query depends on your database.

`SELECT @rownumber\\:=@rownumber+1 as rownumber, column From Table`

Or as JB Nizet suggested in comments, you can use your own logic to map those objects to objects with counter.